# How can I use a built-in pdf function in a module in Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, tcpdf

I am new to **Joomla**. I am currently using **Joomla 1.5** for development. I am developing a form **module** that functions like *providing users to fill up the form and submit it*. Now when a user submits the filled up form, this module should *generate a dynamic pdf file which includes all the submitted data along with the related fields*. Moreover I have to beautify the layout of the file using `css` and `html tags`. I want to use Joomla built in `pdf` function for this. But I have no idea how to manipulate the function for pdf generation. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do that with just a module. The way the Joomla PDF library works (really all PDF librarys work similarly) is that it sends the corresponding HTML to the PDF library for rendering. The PDF library itself does not do anything but convert what it is given in to a PDF. The layout and formatting is all handled outside the library then passed to the library as a complete document. You would need a component that handles the form input and turns it in to the document you wish to turn in to a PDF, then submits the resulting information to the library for display.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Well i have used the tcpdf library for the task . . ))